# Unable to save to database. Submitting form refreshes form page instead

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to carry over player_id and save to the Stakes table referencing that player_id, which is the foreign key for the Stakes table. However, I am not sure how to do so. I have edited my views.py to reflect two of the answers below, but it still seems to refresh the form and not save to the database. The only thing I can think of is this being due to the DateTimeField. However, I am using a copy/pasted date from the database in the exact format so I doubt that would be it.

Models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    SITE_CHOICES = (
        ('FTP', 'Full Tilt Poker'),
        ('Stars', 'Pokerstars'),
        ('UB', 'Ultimate Bet'),
    )
    site_played = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SITE_CHOICES)

class Stakes(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    stakes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount_won = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    last_play_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Last Updated')
```

Views.py

```
def new_stake(request, player_id):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=player_id)
    form = StakeForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        # ...
        stakes = form.cleaned_data['stakes']
        amount_won = form.cleaned_data['amount_won']
        last_played_date = form.cleaned_data['last_played_date']
        stakes_new = Stakes(player = player, 
                stakes = stakes,
                amount_won = amount_won,
                last_played_date = last_played_date)
        stakes_new.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/stakeme/stake_added/') # redirect after POST
else:
    form = StakeForm() # An unbound form
return render_to_response('stakeme/new_stake.html',
                                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

new_stake.html

```
<h1> New Play </h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    Stake Played: <input type="text" name="stakes" id="stakes"/><br>
    Amount Won/Lost: <input type="text" name="amount_won" id="amount_won"/><br>
    Date/Time of play: <input type="text" name="last_play_date" id="last_play_date"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add New Play" />
</form>
```

urls.py

```
(r'^(\d+)/new_stake/$', 'new_stake', name='new_stake' ),
```

forms.py

```
class StakeForm(forms.Form):
    player_id = forms.IntegerField()
    stakes = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount_won = forms.IntegerField()
    last_play_date = forms.DateTimeField()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need that "?" in the urls.py?

Comment: I was fairly certain I did to capture the player_id from the previous page. However, I am looking over the docs now to verify as I'm sure that was a rhetorical question. That said, removing the "?" breaks the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was given to me by someone a different website. He had no desire to repost it here, but I will copy/paste in order to accept the answer and for future reference.

In the view, looking up the player_id should be called even if the POST data was not sent. That ensures you get a 404 anytime there is an invalid player_id in the URL. I simply moved that line of code above the IF statment.

Don't define the form yourself in the template when you can. It avoids missing useful things like error messages when the form is not valid. Django provides some nifty tools to auto generate form HTML for you. I updated the form to look like the following. NOTE: I used 'form.as_table here', but there are some other useful methods such as 'as_p' if you don't like the HTML output as a table. Here is the new new_stake.html:

```
<h1> New Play </h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>{{form.as_table}}</table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add New Play" />
</form>
```

Remove the player_id from your form class if its not actually part of the form (or better yet, make it a hidden field). Also, you should probably be using a ModelForm here, that will auto-populate the form elements for you for the most part after the POST data is recieved. However, I did not make that optimation here. What I did do was remove the player_id line from the form in FORMS.py since it's already in the URL and that seems to be where you wanted to grab it from (rather than a hidden input as suggested above).

```
class StakeForm(forms.Form):
    stakes = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount_won = forms.IntegerField()
    last_play_date = forms.DateTimeField()
```

At this point, you should start seeing you're a bit closer to getting a working form. The problem you were seeing was mainly that your form was not passing the is_valid() check, and if you look at the code, this dropped into showing you the form again. To make things seem worse, you never knew the form was invalid because you designed your own form HTML that did not include the error messages. This fix became more obvious once I used {{form}} in the template rather than using the custom form code in the original html.

A second note, you had miss-spelled the last_play_date as last_played_date. It may have worked the way you had it, but to keep a similar naming convention I renamed this to last_play_date to match the model.

Final note about views.py. You should try not to redirect to a URL defiend as a a string. URLs has a nice feature that lets you name them. You can use the reverse() function to perform a lookup as "reverse('stake_added').

The final VIEWS.py looks like this:

```
def new_stake(request, player_id):
    vars = {}
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=player_id)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted
        form = StakeForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            stakes = form.cleaned_data['stakes']
            amount_won = form.cleaned_data['amount_won']
            last_play_date = form.cleaned_data['last_play_date']
            stakes_new = Stakes(player=player, stakes=stakes,
                amount_won=amount_won, last_play_date=last_play_date)
            stakes_new.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stake_added')) # redirect after POST
    else:
        form = StakeForm() # An unbound form
    # Package up some variables to return
    vars['player'] = player
    vars['form'] = form
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('stakeme/new_stake.html', vars, context_instance=context)
```

And for good measure, here is the final URLS.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(\d+)/new_stake/$', new_stake, name='new_stake'),
    url(r'^stake_added/$', direct_to_template, {'template':'stakeme/stake_added.html'}, name="stake_added"),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like:

```
(r'^(\d+)/new_stake/$', 'new_stake', name='new_stake' ),
```

---

Most likely something erred out while validating your form. You might want to go back to the view to find the errors on the lines of:

```
def new_stake(request, player_id):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted
        form = StakeForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            stakes = form.cleaned_data['stakes']
            amount_won = form.cleaned_data['amount_won']
            last_played_date = form.cleaned_data['last_played_date']
            stakes_new = Stakes(player_id = player_id, 
                        stakes = stakes,
                        amount_won = amount_won,
                        last_played_date = last_played_date)
            stakes_new.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/stakeme/stake_added/') # redirect after POST

        else:
            player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=player_id)
            player.form = StakeForm(request.POST)
            return render_to_response('stakeme/new_stake.html', {'player': player}
                                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=player_id)
        player.form = StakeForm() # An unbound form
        return render_to_response('stakeme/new_stake.html', {'player': player}
                                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Even replacing my urls.py "new_stake" entries with this above line, I still click submit on the form and I get a page not found error. I understand this is due to the "else" section of the views.py redirecting to /stakeme/new_stake.html and not /stakeme/{{ player_id }}/new_stake.html but changing it to that results in a link to stakeme//new_stake, rather than stakeme/1/new_stake.html for example. But how come the form is not submitting to the database? Nothing is written to the database, and it skips to the "else" clause. Something is wrong in the views.py and that is what I can't figure out.

Comment: Same seems to go for the form action. If I change this line `<form action="/stakeme/new_stake/" method="post">` to this line `<form action="/stakeme/{{ player.id }}/new_stake/" method="post">` submitting the form redirects to stakeme//new_stake rather than stakeme/1/new_stake. So the player_id is disappearing. Perhaps this is why nothing is written to the database?

Comment: try <form action="" method="post">

Comment: Nice. That gets rid of the page error. However I still have the issue of nothing saving to the database. Submitting the form essentially just refreshes the page now.

Comment: I think it might be cause of validation errors, or something else going wrong while saving. If you are using chrome, try seeing what kind of error you are getting via the 'Network' tab of 'Developer tools'. It shows the response of each request, in case you are not able to get to the stack trace for detailed errors

Comment: I used Firefox's Error Console and it did not throw any errors when submitting the form.

Comment: Also try displaying the {{ form.errors }} in your template after your do the post submit. You might see if there is something sneaky in there.

Comment: This does not work either. Same issue - seems to refresh the form. I've added {{ form.errors }} as well and it does not appear that I am getting any errors..

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

(notice the new line just below the if request.method and i edited the "stakes_new" line)

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=player_id)
    form = StakeForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        # ...
        stakes = form.cleaned_data['stakes']
        amount_won = form.cleaned_data['amount_won']
        last_played_date = form.cleaned_data['last_played_date']
        stakes_new = Stakes(player = player, 
                    stakes = stakes,
                    amount_won = amount_won,
                    last_played_date = last_played_date)
        stakes_new.save()
```

Comment: This did not save either. Same thing - clicking submit seems to just refresh the screen.

Comment: have you looked in the database and verified that it is not saving?

Comment: Yes. And verified it can be written to by adding a player (I already have that written) and adding a new stake in the Django Admin.

Comment: what does the url conf for this say? ('/stakeme/stake_added/')

Comment: The only thing I can think of, if you can't see anything wrong with the coding of the view, is that the "last_played_date" field is a DateTimeField. However, I've copy and pasted a date from the database in the exact format, so that should not be it, correct?

Comment: I have not added stake_added to the url conf or created an HTML page for it yet. So I should be getting a 404 if the save works correctly.